# Getting all Distribution List from "Global Adress List" Outlook & member in Distribution List WPF

Tags: wpf

i'm writing a new application, and i need to find all the member of the distribution list in Outlook from the "Global Adress List".

After i found all the Distribution List i need to find all the members of the Distribution List.

Finally, i want to get all the information of the member (like contact form).

I found this code to find the members of a Distribution List, but the problem is that i need to choose the Distribution List from outlook and after that it will display all the members.
I want to do it automatically by entering the name of the distribution List before.

```
    private void GetDistributionListMembers()
    {
        gal = outlookApp.Session.GetGlobalAddressList();
        Outlook.SelectNamesDialog snd =
            outlookApp.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog();
        Outlook.AddressLists addrLists =
            outlookApp.Session.AddressLists;
        foreach (Outlook.AddressList addrList in addrLists)
        {
            if (addrList.Name == "My Distribution List")
            {
                snd.InitialAddressList = addrList;
                break;
            }
        }
        snd.NumberOfRecipientSelectors =
            Outlook.OlRecipientSelectors.olShowTo;
        snd.ToLabel = "D/L";
        snd.ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = true;
        snd.AllowMultipleSelection = false;
        snd.Display();
        if (snd.Recipients.Count > 0)
        {
            Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry =
                snd.Recipients[1].AddressEntry;
            if (addrEntry.AddressEntryUserType ==
                Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
                olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry)
            {
                Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList exchDL =
                    addrEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList();
                Outlook.AddressEntries addrEntries =
                    exchDL.GetExchangeDistributionListMembers();
                if (addrEntries != null)
                    foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry exchDLMember
                        in addrEntries)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(exchDLMember.Name);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can Someone please help me with this? i searched a lot in Google but didn't find any solution.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to get all the members of a specific "Distribution List" without choosing it manually, here is the code:

```
    private void GetDistributionListMembers()
    {
        gal = outlookApp.Session.GetGlobalAddressList();
        Outlook.SelectNamesDialog snd =
            outlookApp.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog();
        Outlook.AddressLists addrLists =
            outlookApp.Session.AddressLists;
        foreach (Outlook.AddressList addrList in addrLists)
        {
            if (addrList.Name == "My Distribution List")
            {
                snd.InitialAddressList = addrList;
                break;
            }
        }
        snd.NumberOfRecipientSelectors =
            Outlook.OlRecipientSelectors.olShowTo;
        snd.ToLabel = "D/L";
        snd.ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = true;
        snd.AllowMultipleSelection = false;
        snd.Recipients.Add("My Distribution List");
        snd.Recipients.ResolveAll();
        //snd.Display();
        if (snd.Recipients.Count > 0)
        {
            Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry =
                snd.Recipients[1].AddressEntry;
            if (addrEntry.AddressEntryUserType ==
                Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
                olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry)
            {
                Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList exchDL =
                    addrEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList();
                Outlook.AddressEntries addrEntries =
                    exchDL.GetExchangeDistributionListMembers();
                if (addrEntries != null)
                    foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry exchDLMember
                        in addrEntries)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(exchDLMember.Name);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to find solution for getting all the informations of a contact (like Adress, Manager,...) someone have an idea?